# Does there exist ReLu regression?

Tags: regression, softmax

If softmax regression is multinomial logistic regression, is there anything called ReLu regression?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? Regression for non-negative outcomes?

Comment: I mean regression with a activation function ReLU.

Comment: Does regression besides SVM even use activation functions?

Comment: [Generalized linear models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model) use link functions that are same thing, but ReLU is not one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context of regression analysis, people usually calls these models as threshold models. As far as I know there is a package in R that deals with these models. The package is [chngpt](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/chngpt/vignettes/chngpt-vignette.pdf).